# In how many ways can six letters be removed from "SIXSIXSIX" to make the string "SIX"?

Tags: combinatorics

**My answer:**
10
**My reasoning:**
I used a decision tree to list all of the possible ways and counted them.

1. SIX______
2. SI___X___
3. SI______X
4. S___IX___
5. S___I___X
6. S______IX
7. ___SIX___
8. ___SI___X
9. ___S___IX
10. ______SIX

Is there a more mathematical way of getting this result?

Answer (score 5):

Let $s$ be a string of $n$ distinct letters. The number of not necessarily contiguous subsequences of ($s$ repeated $k$ times) that read $s$ is the same as the number of $n$-multisubsets of $[k]$ (length-$n$ combinations with replacement of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ because there is a bijection: given the multisubset $a_1\dots a_n$ in nondecreasing order pick the $i$-th letter of the $a_i$-th repetition of $s$.

```
EIGHT EIGHT EIGHT EIGHT EIGHT EIGHT, 22356
      ^^      ^            ^      ^
```

Therefore the number of ways is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. In your case $n=k=3$, giving $10$.

Comment: The way I understand your elegant solution is that if $i < j$, then the repetition of the string $s$ from which the $i$th letter is selected is at most the repetition from which the $j$th letter is selected.  Thus, the positions of the repetitions from which the letters are sequentially selected must form a nondecreasing sequence such as $22356$.  However, saying pick the $a_i$th letter from the $i$ repetiton of $s$ makes it sound like you would pick the first letter from the first repetition, the second letter from the second repetition, and so forth.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oops, that was a thinko. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

We count equivalently the number of ways to select three letters from left to right to form the word $SIX$. In order to do so we mark for each letter the position
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
S&I&X&S&I&X&S&I&X\\
1&1&1&2&2&2&3&3&3
\end{array}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{X=1}^3\sum_{I=1}^X\sum_{S=1}^I1}&=\sum_{1\leq S\leq I\leq X\leq 3}1\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
> We observe
>
> - We can choose $X$ at position $1$,$2$ or $3$. Depending on that we can select $I$ at position $1$ up to that of $X$ and similarly we can choose $S$ at position $1$ up to the position of $I$.
> - The number of summands given by the index range $$\color{blue}{1\leq S\leq I\leq X\leq 3}$$ of (2) is the number of ordered tripels $(S,I,X)$ between $1$ and $3$ with repetition. This number is given by the binomial coefficient
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{3+3-1}{3}=\binom{5}{3}\color{blue}{=10}
>   \end{align*}